# Which open source program is similar to the Linux "dialog" command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-scripting, dialog, command-line-interface

The linux *dialog* command is a great tool for creating dialog boxes in terminal windows (e.g. in a bash script).

However, there is a drawback of *dialog* which is that the window is always positioned in the center of the screen.

In particular I would like to use the tail box function, e.g.

```
dialog --tailboxbg MYFILE 20 20
```

... which displays a tail of a file inside a text dialog (just like the built-in tail command).

However, I would like to place the resulting window at different positions on the screen. e.g. just in the top half or the lower half. *dialog* does not provide such functionality.

Is there any way to move the windows provided by *dialog* or can someone recommend an alternative tool which is capable of this?

Comment: Btw, why do you want the dialog to appear in a different position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to position the dialog wherever you like using *dialog*'s `--begin` switch (http://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog). However, to create dynamically sized dialogs, that work no matter what size your terminal window is, you will need to access the terminal window dimensions using `tput`. Then you can do the following in your bash script:

```
x=$(tput cols)
y=$(tput lines)
bx=10 # some offset
by=10 # how far down the window should be displayed
padbottom=2
# centered on width                                                     
dwidth=$(($x - $((bx * 2))))
# leave some padding at the bottom
dheight=$(($y - $((by + $padbottom))))
dialog --begin $by $bx --tailbox MY_FILE $dheight $dwidth
```

**Result:** horizontally centered dialog box on the lower half of your terminal window.

**Warning:** you may wish to add some extra checks in case the window size is very small.

Comment: but how can I work with dialog command and with vmctrl ? ( +1)

Comment: First you open your dialog. Then get a handle on the dialog window. Then use wmctrl to control the position of the window. I will update the answer with an example when I am at home and I have linux in front of me.

Comment: thx , I not want to give up with dialog and if wmctrl can move the dialog window it will solve my problem

Comment: I have looked only to discover that *dialog* is a text based window maker. I haver personally never used this tool (although I use wmctrl a lot) and from your question I had the impression that it was and X based GUI tool. I have edited your question above and will update my answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

There is only so much you can do with bash.

However for TUI progarms you can do pretty much everything you need with ncurses. 
https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html

There are wrappers over the C functions provided by curses; if you’re already familiar with curses programming in C.